# Does 'On Action' refer to the default action?

Tags: java, javafx, action, scenebuilder

I've just started using the JavaFX Scene Builder and I've noticed that when creating event handlers that 'On Action' tends to mean the same thing as 'On Click' most of the time. So what exactly does this 'On Action' refer to? Is it just the default interaction you have with each element?

Comment: It's always helpful to check out the JavaDocs first. Specifically, you can find `onAction` definitions under the [`ActionEvent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/event/class-use/ActionEvent.html#javafx.scene.control) docs.

Comment: The actual "trigger" for the `onAction()` handler depends on the `Node`. For instance, if you look at the [`onActionProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TextField.html#onActionProperty) for a `TextField`, you'll see that *"The action handler is normally called when the user types the ENTER key."*

Answer (score 3):

You need to look this up in the documentation of the node type you're using. The properties in SceneBuilder correspond to properties of the node type. Multiple node types provide an `onAction` property and it can have different meanings, e.g.:

- The handler is triggered for a `Button`, if it's clicked or the button is focused and the button is activated using the keyboard (e.g. the enter key).
- The handler is triggered for a `TextField`, if the value is "submitted" using a keyboard key, e.g. enter
- The handler is triggered for a `ComboBox`, if a value is selected from the dropdown list or the value is assigned programatically

(The version of SceneBuilder I'm using allows the user to click the property name to open the javadoc in the web browser btw.)